# MoinMoin 1.9 programmatically creating page error: MoinMoin.PageEditor.AccessDenied: You are not allowed to edit this page!

Tags: python, moinmoin

I am trying to create a new wiki page programmatically with MoinMoin. But it is not allowing me to edit the page, how do I provide a user to create this page as?

```
[Fri Mar 11 11:44:35] [root]@[dev] /usr/local/share/moin
# python2.6
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Jun  4 2010, 21:43:07)
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-48)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from MoinMoin.web.contexts import ScriptContext
>>> from MoinMoin.PageEditor import PageEditor
>>> request = ScriptContext('http://wiki.dev.itaas.com')
>>> pe = PageEditor(request, 'MyNewTestPage')
>>> pe.saveText('Hello World!', 0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/MoinMoin/PageEditor.py", line 1068, in saveText
    raise self.AccessDenied, msg
MoinMoin.PageEditor.AccessDenied: You are not allowed to edit this page!
```

After setting a `User` on the `request` object, it creates the page, but then locks up the entire wiki instance from creating or editing and saving any new pages with `401 Unauthorized` errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get a `User` and attach it to the `ScriptContext` object, here called `request`.

```
>>> import MoinMoin.user
>>> user = MoinMoin.user.get_by_email_address(request,'jarrod.roberson@mycompany.com')
>>> request.user = user
>>> pe = PageEditor(request, 'MyNewTestPage')
>>> pe.saveText('Hello World!', 0)
```

There are other ways to look up a `User` this one worked well for me. I am sure there is a better way.

**WARNING:** Make sure you are running your script as the appropriate UID ( in my case apache:apache ) or you will corrupt the entire MoinMoin wiki.